# Map Formik Text-Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I am using material ui text-fields and validating them with Formik. Instead of typing everything down multiple times, I want to map items but I am unable to do so.

```
return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div className="main-content">
              <form
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />

{/* {[{ variant:"outlined", margin:"normal", id:"email", name:"email", label: "Email", value: email, onChange:{change.bind(null, 'email')}
          ].map((item, index) => (
            <TextField></TextField>
          ))} */}

                  <br></br>
                  <CustomButton
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
```

Currently in the commented out part, I get errors on `change.bind`that `(property) change: (name: string, e: React.FormEvent<Element>) => void
',' expected.ts(1005)`

Similarly, If I try to add `helperText:{touched.email ? errors.email : ''}`in the list of parameters to be mapped onto the text-field, I get this:

```
(property) touched: FormikTouched<{
    email: string;
}>
',' expected.ts(1005)
```

on `touched.email`. Same goes for when I try to use `errors.`

```
(property) touched: FormikTouched<{
    email: string;
}>
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FormikTouched<{ email: string; }>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FormikTouched<{ email: string; }>'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to check out the new useFormik hook by Formik. Much cleaner syntax

Comment: have you managed to map your fields? You also have an issue with the commented code, you map the props but you never set them

Comment: If you could reproduce the issue in a codesandox, I will try to help you

Comment: @Sabbin Hello, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-fog-38yqe?file=/src/App.tsx THANKSS

Comment: @Jnl I've added a solution and explanation in the answer below, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the sandbox.

Based on your sandbox I've managed to make the fields iterations through the `map` function.

First separate the unique field props

1. The props that belong to the input, like `name` `id` `label` etc.
2. The props that belong to the component, like `variant` `margin` `handlers` etc.

You will end up with 2 objects.

(1)One that should be abstract to the component and saved in a separate file, you may use the fields in another component later.

Here because you use formik and you need to have a reference key to formik, I've added the `formikRef` in the object.

```js
const fileds = [
  {
    id: "email",
    name: "email",
    formikRef: "email",
    label: "Email"
  },

  {
    id: "name",
    name: "name",
    formikRef: "name",
    label: "Name"
  }
];
```

(2) The second object that should be stored in the component because it resolves the `<TextField/>` props

*I usually wrap them in useMemo hook so it should not be redeclared if the dependency objects are not changed. This is for performance only, you can use direct object also*

```js
const defaultProps = React.useMemo(() => ({
    textField: {
      variant: 'outlined',
      margin: 'normal',
      onChange: props => {
        formik.handleChange(props);
        formik.handleBlur(props);
      },
      onBlur: formik.handleBlur
    }
  }),
  [formik]
);

//without useMemo

const defaultProps = {
  textField: {
    variant: 'outlined',
    margin: 'normal',
    onChange: props => {
      formik.handleChange(props);
      formik.handleBlur(props);
    },
    onBlur: formik.handleBlur
  }
}
```

The final step is to map the props in the render

```js
{
  fileds.map(({ formikRef, ...input }) => (
    <TextField
      key={formikRef}
      helperText={getIn(formik.touched, formikRef) ? getIn(formik.errors, formikRef) : ''}
      error={getIn(formik.touched, formikRef) && Boolean(getIn(formik.errors, formikRef))}
      value={getIn(formik.values, formikRef)}
      {...input}
      {...defaultProps.textField}
    />
  ))
}
```

I've also created a working sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-proskuriakova-5g693)

**LE:** Type checking was an issue but the solution could be found with a little search... It was discussed [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/393)

I've made the corrections and added `getIn` helper function from `Formik` in order to pass the type checking issues.

Comment: The code sandbox gives some type errors on ```formik.touched[formikRef]``` etc etc. Although it seems to work on the sandbox, it won't compile offline on VS.

Comment: Where do you get type errors in the sandbox? I'm not getting anything, not even a warning in the sandbox... How should I know what do you have in VS? I provided an answer from the code you provided in your sandbox.

Comment: That's weird. I attached the screenshot in the qs. I get these error when I open the sandbox. About VS code, I meant that idk how this is compiling here, it doesn't work on VS as in if I implement it outside the code sandbox. Because I got these errors

Comment: @Jnl I've updated the answer and the sandbox, please check

Comment: I'm sorry but due to the overloading error on ```Textfield```, it is still not working for me :/

Comment: @Jnl I fixed the overloading on the `TextField` component in the sandbox, please check

Comment: This works. Could you please also add in the sandbox how I can map a line break ```<br>``` in each map? If I add it after the TextField tag, I get an error.

Comment: You get an error because any two or more react elements need to have a container. Wrap them in an empty tag `.map(<> <TextField..../></br></>)`